# GLSL SSBO memory alignment & padding

Tags: glsl, vulkan, vertex-shader

In my vertex shader, I have a SSBO Array that I use to access individual data parts for each object.

```
struct Object
{
    vec2 vertices[4];
    uint index;
    vec2 position;
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) buffer ObjectBuffer
{
    Object objects[];
};
```

I have no issues accessing the first two elements `vertices` and `index`. However, when I access `position.x`, it gives me the value in `position.y`, and when I access `position.y`, it gives me gibberish.

To fix this, I swapped the order of `index` and `position` in the `Object` struct.

Using my limited knowledge, I assume that due to memory alignment rules it took the largest data type in the struct which is `vec2` (assuming float = 4 bytes, 4 * 2 = 8 bytes). Assuming `uint` is 4 bytes as well, it took the next 4 bytes beside it (which is `position.x`) as padding?

Whilst I was able to resolve this issue (for now) by switching the order, what else can I do to ensure proper memory alignment?

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm your physical memory layout in terms of byte offsets?

I'd expect each object to be 8 byte aligned, containing:

```
32 bytes (vec2 vertices[4])
 4 bytes (index)
 4 bytes (padding, as position needs to be 8 byte aligned)
 8 bytes (position)
```

> What else can I do to ensure proper memory alignment?

Read the `std430` layout rules very carefully (for storage buffers). Note that uniform buffers default to `std140` layout, not `std430`.